# Is there a wpf webcam control with zoom feature?

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam

I need a WPF control with zooming enabled? I am currently using WPFmediakit and it works good but is there a way to do zoom using multiples of doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use WPF's built-in ScaleTransform. WPF already has the built-in ability to scale anything, so you shouldn't need the VideoCaptureElement control from the media kit to provide any zooming support of its own.

Comment: Wouldn't that be more pixelated than say if i was using the zoom thats already in the camera(just assuming here - i have no idea), like the one thats used for facetracking, or is that done with software aswell.

Comment: Configure the VideoCaptureElement's desired pixel width and height to be the full camera resolution, you'll have as much detail as possible. You can zoom out with a scale transform of 0.5, 0.25, etc. And obviously, there's no way you can get more detail than the camera is able to provide - zooming in will be rather blurry, and  will eventually pixelate if you zoom far enough. That's fundamentally unavoidable, no matter what tech you use. (If your camera has an optical zoom, that's different, but most webcams dan't, so I don't think there's a standard API for that.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more clear about what it exactly is you want.
If you want to use the camera's (optionally) built-in zoom then that has nothing to do with WPF.
If on the other hand you want to zoom in on the image-output (Framebuffer) of the camera,
you can just use WPF's ScaleTransform.